# Cannot get discord to show error in chat

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make my bot tell a user if there is a error by spitting out `You do not have the permissions {}` But when I try to use this code:

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def ban(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, content: str):
    if ctx.message.author == client.user:
        return
    if ctx.message.author.server_permissions.administrator:
        msg = (str(member) + "has been banned for" + str(content)).format(ctx.message)
        await client.send_message(member, content)
        await client.ban(member)
        await client.send_message(ctx.message.channel, msg)
@ban.error
async def ban_error(error, ctx):
    if isinstance(error, CheckFailure):
        msg = "Sorry but you do not have the permissions {}".format(ctx.message.author.mention)  
        await client.send_message(ctx.message.channel, msg)
```

The discord bot dms the user and there is no errors in the python console and if I remove the `@ban.error` piece I get a too low of a permission error.

Comment: also it doesnt even ban people and the member has been banned for content doesn't come up in the server chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CheckFailure` only gets raised if a [check](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#checks) fails.  There are no checks in your code, so this never happens.  You can convert your `if` statement to a check very easily using [`commands.has_permission`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.has_permissions):

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
@has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def ban(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, content: str):
    msg = "{} has been banned for {}".format(ctx.message.author.mention, content)
    await client.send_message(member, content)
    await client.ban(member)
    await client.send_message(ctx.message.channel, msg)
```

It may be the case that the error handler is suppressing valuable error information.  We can just call the bots built in error handling for any other errors that are not `CheckFailure`s

```
from discord.ext.commands import CheckFailure
from discord import Forbidden


@ban.error
async def ban_error(error, ctx):
    if isinstance(error, CheckFailure):
        msg = "Sorry but you do not have the permissions {}".format(ctx.message.author.mention)  
        await client.send_message(ctx.message.channel, msg)
    elif isinstance(error, Forbidden):
        await client.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "I do not have the correct permissions")
    else:
        print(error)
        await client.on_command_error(error, ctx)
```

Comment: Using your code still doesn't ban the user or spit back the reason their banned or if there was an error doing it

Comment: still the same outcome (btw if bot is not client I just get errors)

Comment: Try now.  You're likely getting a `403: FORBIDDEN` error if your bot does not have the necessary permissions to ban/message people.

Comment: im now getting these error throughout my code `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 723, in _read_ready
    data = self._sock.recv(self.max_size)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer`

Comment: Neither of these problems (too low permissions and connection resets) can be solved by code.  You need to get your bot higher permissions.  The connection reset by peer means that discord is closing the connection between you and the API.

Comment: Ok it works if I give it a role with admin privaleges but is there any way to do this automatically when it joins a server

Comment: and also it doesn't spit out error message on discord

Comment: Yes.  Use the OAuth URL generator from your bots page to set the permissions you want it to have.  Then people will add your bot by going to that url.  Your bots page can be found here: https://discordapp.com/developers/applications/me

Comment: Ok so that worked but I had to add the `msg = "has been.....` after the else piece and that fixed the error issue