# Discord clear command limited to owner only

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

Extremely new to discord bots. I am looking to limit a clear command to delete messages to owner only. I would also like to return a simple message of "you don't have permissions to use this command" if the user who calls the command doesn't have permission. I have currently written the following:

```
async def is_owner(ctx):

    return ctx.author.id == *my userid*

@client.command(pass_context=True)

@commands.check(is_owner)

async def clear(ctx, amount=5):

    channel = ctx.message.channel

    messages = []

    async for message in client.logs_from(channel, limit=int(amount)):

        messages.append(message)

    await client.delete_messages(messages)

    await client.say('Messages deleted')
```

While this does function, currently any user that runs it is able to execute the command. Not sure what I'm missing. I appreciate any direction or advice to correcting this issue.

Error after making the def is_owner(ctx)correction is as follows:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 857, in on_message
    yield from self.process_commands(message)
  File "F:\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 846, in process_commands
    yield from command.invoke(ctx)
  File "F:\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 367, in invoke
    yield from self.prepare(ctx)
  File "F:\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 344, in prepare
    self._verify_checks(ctx)
  File "F:\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 338, in _verify_checks
    if not self.can_run(ctx):
  File "F:\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 438, in can_run
    return all(predicate(context) for predicate in predicates)
  File "F:\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 438, in <genexpr>
    return all(predicate(context) for predicate in predicates)
  File "f:\Discord Bots\First\bot.py", line 19, in is_owner
    return ctx.author.id == 'MY USERID'
AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'author'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably seeing an error along the lines of `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'is_owner' was never awaited` that means you gave something a coroutine when it wasn't expecting one, so it's value was ignored.

On the async branch, `commands.check` only works on functions not coroutines. Change your `is_owner` coroutine to a function by removing `async`

```
def is_owner(ctx):
    return ctx.message.author.id == *my userid*
```

Comment: The initial error you stated in regards to coroutine was the error I was receiving. I should have probably included that. I made the change you suggested but I am now getting several traceback errors in debugging.

Comment: I tried to paste the string of errors here however it is far too long. I apologize at my novice mistakes I am new to stackoverflow

Comment: @RichBiggs you should edit the error message into your question (highlight it and press Ctrl+K for block formatting)

Comment: Thank you Mr. Haugh. I have pasted in the errors. Replacing my userid with text, not sure if this is necessary.

Comment: @RichBiggs On async, `ctx` doesn't have a `author`, it has a `message` that has an `author`

Comment: I don't comprehend what you are stating. I think I may be in well over my head. May just be best for me to leave this until I get a bit more experience. I have been successful adding other things such as role assignment on joining, say commands, and chat filter. But your most recent response isn't making sense to me. I appreciate all the time and effort you have volunteered.

Comment: @RichBiggs Just change it to `return ctx.message.author.id == *my userid*`

Comment: Mr. Haugh you are awesome. Thank you very much for all your assistance. It still errors if the id doesn't match mine, which I will look into. I'm hoping to just use a say or send message command to notify the user they don't have permissions to use this command. As I am new to stackoverflow do I use the checkmark to help you in return? I have upvoted your original comment but get a message that because my rep is low it doesn't display but is counted.

Comment: @RichBiggs Don't worry about it. You can write an [error handler](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#error-handling) that can catch the `CheckFailure` exception and send a message to the appropriate user.  You can see an example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51256425/6779307)

Comment: Mr. Haugh the example you provided, worked flawlessly. Obviously just changing to the proper terms. Thank you very much for all your assistance with this!

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a `@commands.is_owner()` for your function.

Don't try to delete your messages with that command

Here's `discord.py` solution for deleting messages:

```py
@commands.is_owner()
async def clear(ctx, amount=5):
    deleted = await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
```

For more info on purge check out [discord.py reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=purge#discord.TextChannel.purge)

Answer (score 0):

Your decorator `@commands.check(is_owner)` could contain the problem. Try to see if that decorator can run and if it does, then check that for any problems like i said. Additionally, Discord API docs states that messages older than 2 weeks cannot be deleted as it will "interrupt Discord's message database".

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it

```py
@client.command()
async def clear(ctx, amount=1):
    if ctx.message.author.id(YOUR ID HERE)
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit = amount + 1) 
        # this is because we want to include the message that calls the command
    else:
        ctx.send("I'm sorry, you cannot do that.")
```

have fun coding, if this doesn't work feel free to dm me: officer grr#6609

Comment: Or, instead of DMing, leave a comment so others could benefit from the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@client.command() @commands.has_any_role(YourRoleID)

    async def clear(self, ctx, limit: int=None):
        success = 0
        failed = 0
        async for msg in ctx.message.channel.history(limit=limit):
            if ctx.message.author != client.user:
                try:
                    await msg.delete()
                    success += 1
                except:
                    failed += 1

        print(f"Removed {success} messages with {failed} errors")
```